# Do any of thrift, protobuf, avro, etc support quering on encoded data directly?

Tags: data-structures, protocol-buffers, thrift, avro

Do any of thrift, protobuf, avro, etc support quering on the resulting compact data? Or would something like a thrift-server first have to de-encode the compact data before being able to query it?

**background:** since there might be an entirely different answer to my usecase I'm not seeing.

I've sketched out a custom datastructure on paper (akin to a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)), which will contain tens/hundreds of millions of key-value pairs. The whole stuff needs to be in RAM so it needs to be compact.

For this reason I'm probably skipping the normal kv-stores, since there's just too much overhead in encoding. They can't optimize for the specicialized case of the structure. (Redis has the least overhead per key afaik but it isn't enough: 100+ bytes per key)

I've looked into [Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/), [Protobuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/), [Avro](http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html), [Messagepack](http://msgpack.org/), which will all allow me to encode the data to a nice compact structure all taking care of the specific opportunities of my datastructure (encoding keys as 1 or 2 bytes, bitpacking, values are fixed length, etc.)

However, It's completely unclear to me if any of these protocols/techniques will allow me to **query** on the compacted datastructure as is, or if the data-structure has to be de-encode before quering? If the latter, well than this whole exercise hasn't been of much use to me.

As an alternative, I've thought of looking at other programming languages (c/c++ probably although I've never dabbled with it) that probably would allow me to have very tight memory control over structs (As opposed to Node/javascript which is extremely bad with that)

Anyone?

Comment: They need to be decoded for querying

Comment: @BruceMartin: mind making that an answer I'll accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They need to be decoded for querying